# How to open KML file in Google maps for android?

Tags: google-maps, kml, android

Does anybody know how to open the KML file in Google maps for android?

Comment: I think you are wrong. I know for google earth but I think there is a solution with htm link, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it show no research effort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a map in "My Maps" (https://mapsengine.google.com/map/). You can import your kml there. You can find more information about the limitations in https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps. After that, you can access the map you created from the Google maps app in your device.

Comment: How to import? I couldn't find it easily. Ah click legend then import.

Comment: After I downloaded the map I struggeled to find it on my phone's google maps app. Here are the instructions that helped me find it: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3045850?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid

Answer (score -1):

Try to install googleearth for android or try to make html file like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931281/open-local-kml-file-in-google-maps-on-android